Orthogonal Projection of a Point onto an oriented Ellipse in R^3
Read through Find projection point on elipse where the answer goes over the 2D case of projecting a point $\textbf{p}$ onto an ellipse defined by $\textbf{x}(t) = \textbf{c} + \textbf{u}\cos(t) + \textbf{v}\sin(t)$ where $\textbf{c}$ is the center of the ellipse, $\textbf{u}$ is the vector that defines the length and direction of one of the semi major/minor axis and $\textbf{v}$ defines the length and direction of the other semi major/minor axis. Both of which are orthogonal to each other. The equation below is derived from the relationship $(\textbf{x}(t) - \textbf{p})
\cdot\textbf{x}'(t) = 0$ $$C_1\cos(t) + C_2\sin(t) + C_3\sin(2t) = 0$$ where $$C_1 = (\textbf{c} - \textbf{p})\cdot \textbf{v}, C_2 = (\textbf{p} - \textbf{c})\cdot \textbf{u}, C_3 = \frac{1}{2}(\textbf{u}\cdot \textbf{u} - \textbf{v}\cdot \textbf{v})$$
It seems this equation which is claimed to have 4 roots at most (when solving for t) is solved best when you have a fixed ellipse with actual numbers and are trying to solve it with a Computer Algebra System for a specific case of an ellipse. Trying to solve this symbolically to get the generalization gives very lengthy equations (tried in Mathematica).
I need this for some 3D code where the position and form of my ellipse is dynamic so $\textbf{c}, \textbf{u}, \textbf{v}$ can change rapidly. So what do I do? I tried Numerical Methods such as the Newton-Raphson but I have no clue how to get all 4 roots (if there are any) all the time. Without all 4, you cannot check for the closest using $||\textbf{x}(t_i) - \textbf{p}||_2$. Any help would be appreciated on the direction to take, if I'm misunderstanding something, any assumptions are incorrect, etc.
There's also this paper "Least-squares orthogonal distances fitting of circle, sphere, ellipse, hyperbola, and parabola" by Sung Joon Ahn, et. al., but I'm not mathematically mature enough to read this quite yet.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Ah, didn't know Weierstrass Substitution was used in things like this. Pretty nice how it becomes a quartic. This definitely does give me a direction. Now my code will need a Quartic Solver. Thank you.

My code has been working for a while now. But there is a case that I'm approximating which works fine but I'm wondering what exactly is going on in the math. For example, if I plug in $p = <0, 5>, c = <5, 5>, u = <3, 0>, v = <0, 1.5>$ this'll return (8, 5) despite (2, 5) being the answer. I'm guessing this is because $C_1 = (p - c).v = 0$ due to orthogonality reducing the polynomial to $a_3z^3 + a_1z = 0 \implies z(a_3z^2 + a_1) = 0$ which only has one real solution ($z = 0$) due to the solution of $a_3z^2 + a_1 = 0$ being imaginary in this case -a1/a3 < 0.

Here is a link to my Python Code to test out an Orthogonal Projection onto an Ellipse and see what I'm talking about: https://github.com/DinoDonald/PointToEllipse/blob/main/main.py
